# PGFplots: Only draw a label for every n-th data point

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I've drawn the following graph

[image: Graph]

Using this code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
2019-05,64
2019-06,66
2019-07,59
2019-08,56
2019-09,64
2019-10,55
2019-11,57
2019-12,51
2020-01,50
2020-02,54
2020-03,51
2020-04,53
2020-05,49
2020-06,49
2020-07,52
2020-08,52
2020-09,48
2020-10,38
2020-11,37
2020-12,36
2021-01,32
2021-02,33
2021-03,37
2021-04,43
2021-05,37
2021-06,34
2021-07,39
2021-08,36
2021-09,36
2021-10,34
2021-11,42
2021-12,38
2022-01,40
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth, compat=1.18}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,]{data.csv}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{a},
    x tick label style = {font=\small, align=center, rotate=70, anchor=north east},
]
\addplot table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma, x expr=\coordindex]{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't want the x-axis to be so crowded. It would be nice if I could somehow only draw a label for every 5th data point. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is categorical, it is impossible to specify the `xtick distance` the normal way. The below codes first capture the number of rows from the table, then set the `xtick` based on your desired interval.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
2019-05,64
2019-06,66
2019-07,59
2019-08,56
2019-09,64
2019-10,55
2019-11,57
2019-12,51
2020-01,50
2020-02,54
2020-03,51
2020-04,53
2020-05,49
2020-06,49
2020-07,52
2020-08,52
2020-09,48
2020-10,38
2020-11,37
2020-12,36
2021-01,32
2021-02,33
2021-03,37
2021-04,43
2021-05,37
2021-06,34
2021-07,39
2021-08,36
2021-09,36
2021-10,34
2021-11,42
2021-12,38
2022-01,40
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth, compat=1.18}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,]{data.csv}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathsetmacro\numrows{\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,5,...,\numexpr\numrows-1},
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{a},
    x tick label style = {font=\small, align=center, rotate=70, anchor=north east},
]
\addplot table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma, x expr=\coordindex]{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: mandatory [welcome to Tex.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)